# Modal con error al enviar FORM

Tags: php, sql, modal

Tengo un form con datos para editar, que se muestra en un modal.

Todo funciona perfecto al momento de editar el usuario, pero...

Al ENVIAR el formulario, se cierra el modal, se abre en el navegador la página que estaba adentro del modal, aparece el Sweetalert de confirmación o error y después se carga la página que indico.

¿Por qué se abre la página del modal, después de enviar el form?

**Código que llama a la función que abre el modal:**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_usuario_edicion">
<img id="img_editar" src="../imagenes/editar.png" name="editar_usuario" alt="Ícono editar" onclick="usuario_editar('<?php echo $usuarios['id_usuario'] ?>')"></a>
```

**Código que abre el modal con la página correspondiente y el ID del usuario de la tabla:**

```
function usuario_editar(id_editar) {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '../head_menu/usuarios_edicion.php',
data:{id:id_editar},
success: function(data) {
$('#modal_usuario_edicion .modal-body').html(data);
    }
});
}
```

**Código de la página que se abre en el modal (funciona la carga de los datos de la tabla en el modal, se actualiza la base si hay modificación):**

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['user_cargo'])) {?>  

<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="es">

<head>

</head>

<body>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post" id="usuario_edit">
    <div class="container">    
        <?php
            $usuario_id=$_POST['id']; // ESTA LÍNEA ME TIRA EL ERROR

            include("../conexsesion/conexion.php");

            $sql_usuarios="SELECT usuarios.id_usuario, .usuarios.legajo, usuarios.dni, usuarios.apellido, usuarios.nombre, usuarios.mail, usuarios.cargo FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario='$usuario_id'";
            $consulta_usuarios=mysqli_query($acceso,$sql_usuarios);
            while ($usuarios=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta_usuarios)) {
                
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" id="txt_id_usuario" name="usuario_id" required value="<?php echo $usuarios['id_usuario']; ?>">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="txt_apellido" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label label">* Apellido/s:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input
                    type="text" class="form-control txt" id="txt_apellido" name="usuario_apellido" value="<?php echo $usuarios['apellido']; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="txt_nombre" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label label">* Nombre/s:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control txt" id="txt_nombre" name="usuario_nombre" value="<?php echo $usuarios['nombre']; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="txt_cargo" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label label">* Cargo:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select name="usuario_cargo" id="txt_cargo_select">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        $sql_cargo="SELECT id_cargo, cargo FROM cargos";
                        $consulta_cargo=mysqli_query($acceso,$sql_cargo);
                        while ($cargo=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta_cargo)) {
                           echo '<option value="'.$cargo['id_cargo'].'">'.$cargo['cargo'].'</option>';                                         
                        }                           
                    ?>                          
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php                    
            }
        ?>
        <div class="row" align="center">
            <div class="col inferior">
                <button type="submit" class="btn formulario-btn" id="btn_actualizar" name="actualizar" disabled><img src="../imagenes/confirmar.ico"/><b>&nbsp ACTUALIZAR</b></button>
                &nbsp &nbsp
                <button type="button" class="btn formulario-btn" id="btn_cancelar" data-dismiss="modal"><img src="../imagenes/cancelar.ico"/><b>&nbsp CANCELAR</b></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/imta.js"> </script>       
</body>
</html>  

<?php

if (isset($_POST['actualizar'])) {

include("../conexsesion/conexion.php");

$usuarioid=$_POST['usuario_id'];
$usuario_apellido=$_POST['usuario_apellido'];
$usuario_nombre=$_POST['usuario_nombre'];
$usuario_cargo=$_POST['usuario_cargo'];

$sql="UPDATE usuarios SET legajo='$usuario_legajo', apellido='$usuario_apellido', nombre='$usuario_nombre', cargo='$usuario_cargo' WHERE id_usuario='$usuarioid'";

if (mysqli_query($acceso,$sql)) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
        'usuario_edit_ok();',
        '</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
        'usuario_edit_error();',
        '</script>';
}
}
?>
<?php

} else {
header("location:../index.php");
}
?>
```

**Este es el error que me tira la página. Funciona la actualización a la base de datos, pero al volver a cargar la tabla, me abre la página del modal con ese error. Esa línea debería ejecutarse al abrir el modal, no al cerrarlo. Acá es donde no comprendo. He puesto, desde mi ignorancia, el error_reporting(0); pero la página aparece igual que la foto, pero sin la leyenda.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `$_POST` no tiene `id`.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Sí sí, es así, pero cómo puedo hacer para evitarlo? Toco EDITAR en USUARIOS, Se abre un modal que mediante AJAX pasa el ID de ese usuario. En el modal se carga USUARIO_EDITAR. Al confirmar la edición, las modificacione se hacen, pero antes, el navegador me abre la página del modal, me muestra ese error, carga el sweetalert y finaliza. Ese ID del $_POST la página lo recibe al cargarse el modal. ¿Cómo lo puedo evitar al enviarse el form?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru El tema sería enviar el formulario sin recargar la página que está en el modal que es la que me abre el navegador y me tira el error.